# Error with Instantiate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm getting error on second line with this code:

```
var myNewSmoke = Instantiate (cube, temp, transform.rotation);
myNewSmoke.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
```

error:

> Type `UnityEngine.Object` does not contain a definition for
>   `transform` and no extension method `transform` of type
>   `UnityEngine.Object` could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

I don't understand the error. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate is a method of Object Class. You're trying to access `gameobject.transform` which is inside GameObject Class.

GameObject Class Implements Object Class like everything else so you have to cast it into GameObject first.

`var myNewSmoke = Instantiate (cube, temp, transform.rotation) as GameObject;`

Or

`GameObject myNewSmoke = Instantiate (cube, temp, transform.rotation) as GameObject;`

Comment: How do we destroy the previous instance of `cube`?

Comment: `Destroy(myNewSmoke)`